# select count from joined table

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to select the likes count of each post. In my code, the table is T3. I can't seem to get the desired results and i am unsure why. Please help.

```
function timeLineSql(Id, ifRoute) {
  var preparedStatement, query;
  ifRoute == "post" ? 
  (preparedStatement = [Id, lastIdOfPosts],  query = "SELECT T1.postTitle, T1.youtubeUrl, T1.posterId, T1.textarea, T1.category, T1.postTime, T1.id, T2.name, T2.title, T2.pathToProfilePicture, COUNT(T3.likerId) FROM posts AS T1 " +
  "JOIN likes AS T3 ON T3.idOfPost = T1.id " +
  "JOIN singleHorizontal AS T2 ON T1.posterId = T2.id AND T1.posterId = ? AND T1.id > ? ORDER BY T1.id LIMIT 1")
  : (preparedStatement = [Id],  query = "SELECT T1.postTitle, T1.youtubeUrl, T1.posterId, T1.textarea, T1.category, T1.postTime, T1.id, T2.name, T2.title, T2.pathToProfilePicture FROM posts AS T1 " + 
  "JOIN singleHorizontal AS T2 ON T1.posterId = T2.id AND T1.posterId = ? ORDER BY T1.id LIMIT 1");
  return { ps: preparedStatement, q: query };
}
```

Comment: You probably have to `GROUP BY ( T3.idOfPost )` but that's just a guess. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Looks like your `AND`s should be `WHERE`s.

Comment: ? not sure what you mean by this